# Log4j: Multiple categories with specializations

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have some doubts about the categories of log4j.

I have three categories ...

- `Program`
- `Program.BUILD`
- `Program.QUERY`

When I define the following log4j.properties:

> log4j.logger.program = DEBUG, stdout, file
>
> log4j.logger.program.BUILD = DEBUG, file

and in Java I call:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("program.BUILD");
```

assume that the stdout and file are the appender to console and file respectively.

My problem is that when I specify the two categories, as shown, `program.BUILD log's are written to console and file. But he was only specified for the file appender. The log4j then makes it an inheritance?

I would like to specify three categories, but that when specified he caught the `program.BUILD` ONLY what was specified in that category, without taking the generic category (program).
But if not specified, the categories `program.QUERY` and `program.BUILD`, was picking up the program category, because it would represent the two that were not specified.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Log4j has an inheritance system. You can disable it (that is, not let the log messages bubble up to the parent category) with the "additivity=false" flag.

> Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to
>   all the appenders in that logger as well as the appenders higher in
>   the hierarchy. In other words, appenders are inherited additively from
>   the logger hierarchy. For example, if a console appender is added to
>   the root logger, then all enabled logging requests will at least print
>   on the console. If in addition a file appender is added to a logger,
>   say C, then enabled logging requests for C and C's children will print
>   on a file and on the console. It is possible to override this default
>   behavior so that appender accumulation is no longer additive by
>   setting the additivity flag to false.

(See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: @Croisier Where do I add this flag "additivity=false"? in logger object that is program.BUILD with the command logger.setAdditivity(false)? If I dont set the program.BUILD, it will inherit from program anyway?

Comment: Like this (assuming you use the .properties file-based configuration) : log4j.additivity.program.BUILD=false